# No supported authentication methods available

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am unable to logon to my GCE VM instance, what I did was following:

1. Use PuTTY Key Generate to generate a public key and a private key.
2. I copied public key in Metabase section under Developers Console. Followed the format username:. Something like:

Administrator:ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAiNbeEUl.......

I am sure there is no new line problem with my copy/paste.

1. I loaded my private key using PuTTY but I am receiving following error:

**Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available(server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi0with-mic)**

In the event log, it reads:

**Offered public key
Server refused our key**

## Help needed:

The steps are pretty straight forward and the error is very general. I basically tried steps I can find on internet but still no go.

Not sure how can I move forward??

Answer (score 1):

I just made a test and I was able to login into one of my machines, but when I copied the public key, I just added the value generated:

*ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAqwAyb....*

without the '*Administrator*' username.

In the 'Metadata' menu in your Developers Console, when adding the new key, it generates a 'username', in my case it was 'rsa-key-20140602'. So in Putty, when addintg the Host Name, I did as

rsa-key-20140602@10.10.10.10

Note: 10.10.10.10 has to be the external IP address for you VM.

Mary

Answer (score 0):

Though not with [[image]google-compute-engine](/questions/tagged/google-compute-engine), I was having the same problem with logging into my server via [putty](/questions/tagged/putty), found out that my private key was not loaded in this session.

So, if you are having similar problem, try checking that your private key is loaded inside

`PuTTy > Connection > SSH > Auth > "Private Key For Authentication."`

Doesn't always happen, but I think somehow the PuTTy session got deleted or something.